JasperReports PDF/A-1A
I am trying to create a PDF in PDF/A-1A conformance with jasperreports and have read through several forums and found some settings.
net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdfa.conformance=
net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tagged=
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name=
net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdfa.icc.profile.path=
net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.exclude.key.TransparentImage=
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.embedded=
net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.language=

but I still get some error messages during validation.

An annotation dictionary must contain the key F. The Print flag bit of the F key must be set to 1 and its Hidden, Invisible and NoView flag bits must be set to 0

A PDF/A-1 OutputIntent is an OutputIntent dictionary, as defined by PDF Reference 9.10.4, that is included in the file's OutputIntents array and has GTS_PDFA1 as the value of its S key and a valid ICC profile stream as the value its DestOutputProfile key


I have

one F Flag in my pdf and have set its value to 1, but still I am facing this error.

DestOutputProfile and /S /GTS_PDFA1 are set at the beginning but this error wont go away


Does anyone know how I can fix these errors?
Thank you all in advance
